# Combine - receiveOn works, subscribeOn doesn't, regardless of thread

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, combine

I am able to "subscribe" to a publisher as long as I don't include the keyword `subscribe`

```
var somePublisher: AnyPublisher<(), Never> { get }
...
cancellable = somePublisher
   .receive(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))
   .sink(receiveValue: { _ in
       Log.d("This works... isMainThread=\(Thread.isMainThread)")
   })

prints "This works... isMainThread=false
```

But if I add a subscriber, so that I can use modifiers like map {}, on the background thread (or any thread for that matter, I tried main), sink never runs.

```
var somePublisher: AnyPublisher<(), Never> { get }
...
cancellable = somePublisher
   .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))
   .receive(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))
   .sink(receiveValue: { _ in
       Log.d("This DOES NOT work... isMainThread=\(Thread.isMainThread)")
   })
OR
var somePublisher: AnyPublisher<(), Never> { get }
...
cancellable = somePublisher
   .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.main)
   .receive(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))
   .sink(receiveValue: { _ in
       Log.d("This DOES NOT work... isMainThread=\(Thread.isMainThread)")
   })
Nothing prints, the breakpoint is never hit. Sink never executes
```

What am I missing here? What about the subscribe is causing my subscriber to fail?

Comment: What is `somePublisher`? `.subscribe(on:)` affects how (on what thread) the upstream publishers are subscribed to, so there could be a possible race condition there. Why do you need `.subscribe(on:)` - it's more common to use `.receive(on:)`, and not all publishers necessarily do what you'd expect with `.subscribe(on:)`

Comment: Works fine, tested with Just. This is something with your publisher, maybe deadlock. You can add `.handleEvents(...)` to track what and when happens.

Comment: @NewDev @Asperi it's a `PassthroughSubject<(), Never>()`

Comment: @CodeWiget, So, if your subject sends a value synchronously, it's probably a race condition between sending and subscribing on a particular thread.

Comment: @NewDev i think you're right, I think it was a race condition